# Stream based JSON parsing on Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, stream

How to parse JSON being downloaded as a stream on Swift? The stream gives incomplete JSON data each time.
This is because I have to download MBs of data, the main component of which is a long array of objects, and I do not want the user to wait till I get the complete data. Is it possible to keep parsing the JSON data sequentially while streaming?
Basically, something like what Jackson allows on Android, or a YAJLiOS Parser implementation for Swift

Comment: Wow, no action on this in over a year and a half.

Comment: JSON parsing is not hard at all. Why not write your own parser?

Comment: Maybe is better approach if you send the `json` from the server in parts. I mean, X number of elements each time

Answer (score 11):

Basically, what you require is a SAX parser. NSJSONSerialization is a DOM parser. One such implementation for sax parsing is here

https://github.com/dhoerl/SAX-JSON-Parser-ForStreamingData

where the data is parsed as and when the data is received. For more info check this answer
[iPad - Parsing an extremely huge json - File (between 50 and 100 mb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932492/ipad-parsing-an-extremely-huge-json-file-between-50-and-100-mb)

Comment: Yeah, this is again an Obj-C based approach. I was looking for something Swift based actually.